# iOS8: Best way to autocomplete address searching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I have an app where users are allowed to enter an address in a text field. I'd like to have a tableView associated that populates with auto-completed guesses of the address they're looking for (e.g. the way Uber does). I've build my app thus far with MapKit - is there a way to do this with MapKit or is the Google Maps SDK the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete is a simple objective-c wrapper around the Google Places Autocomplete API.

Look at this API from github which might be helpful- https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

Usage shown as per link. Adding the .h file you can have access to the functions which implement the Google places API from within the function. You can set parameters like partial address string, radius, language your app uses, your location (lat,long)

```
#import "SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery.h"

...

SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *query = [SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery query];
query.input = @"185 berry str";
query.radius = 100.0;
query.language = @"en";
query.types = SPPlaceTypeGeocode; // Only return geocoding (address) results.
query.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.76999, -122.44696)
```

Then, call -fetchPlaces to ping Google's API and fetch results. The resulting array will return objects of the SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace class.

```
[query fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Places returned %@", places);
}];
```

It also has a example project which can be used.

Comment: i am not able to use it. i have downloaded this objective-c wrapper. when i am using these class getting lots of error like some string is not found can you help

Answer (score 0):

**Just FYI it is against the Google's terms and conditions you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies)**

They have clearly mentioned that

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a
>   map, that map must be provided by Google.

**Alternatively you can use Apple Map Kit itself for achieving this.**

You can use `MKLocalSearchRequest` for it.

> **A SAMPLE PROJECT CAN BE DOWNLOAD FROM [HERE](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/MapKitTutorial).**